# Is there an event that fires when URL changes

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Is there an event that fires when ANY part of the URL changes?

Detecting URL changes has been asked many times, but the general answers are outdated (~2010).

**Summary of existing answers:**

- You can use `popstate` for some situations (it does fire for all URL changes).
- You can use `onbeforeunload` when a page is being navigated away (and unloading its resources).
- You can use the `hashchange` event to watch for hash fragment changes.
- Otherwise it seems the conventional answer is still to **poll** for a change to window.location.

Is polling still the best solution in **2016**?  It's surprising that there isn't an event for this given the other advancements in `location` and its APIs, so that's why I'm posting this question.

Comment: Nope, no common event for every change, but you could create one based on the other events.

Comment: @adeneo - which events are you referring to? Currently I'm trying to detect the URL changes that occur on YouTube when you navigate between videos.

Comment: I think using popstate ist the best solution and also well supportet. Are there any specific requirements why you do not want to use it?

Comment: @Wolfgang - it does not fire on all URL changes. From the docs: `Note that just calling history.pushState() or history.replaceState() won't trigger a popstate event. The popstate event is only triggered by doing a browser action such as a click on the back button (or calling history.back() in JavaScript).`

Comment: In what context exactly are you trying to access YouTube? A content script, from the console, or what? You'd have to figure out exactly what Google does when the video changes, and then figure out a way to capture that event in a content script or something ?

Comment: In my situation - I'm injecting javascript (it's a chrome plugin). I tried popstate, but no success. I'll keep looking.

Comment: @Donny: Just had a look at YouTube and I always get a page refresh when navigating. So an alternatie could also be a the document.onreadystatechange event during load

Answer (score 1):

event when using history.pushState() should be enough to take action on href change:

```
window.addEventListener('popstate', listener);

const pushUrl = (href) => {
  history.pushState({}, '', href);
  window.dispatchEvent(new Event('popstate'));
};
```